# Login with Email/Password without enabling it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

My current registration process looks like this:

1. App sends a registration request via my REST Api to my backend with information like username, password, email etc.
2. My backend checks if the username is available. If it is, it creates a new user with the admin api. If this is successful as well it saves the username to the realtime db.

When I want to log in with `loginWithEmailAndPassword` it says that I can't because PasswordLogin is disabled.

Since I don't want anybody to just register with `registerWithEmailAndPassword` I want to keep it disabled.

My question now is, how can I log a user in without enabling Email/Password?
Or would there even be a possibility to exploit the system when I enable Email/Password?

**EDIT**: What I'm not sure about is if registrations with `registerWithEmailAndPassword` are guaranteed to be from my app?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to sign the user in to a disabled provider. I'm actually quite surprised that you can register them.

There is no way to prevent users from registering after you enable the provider.

But it's quite easy to only allow users that your administrative back-end created access to certain data. Just make the admin script write the UID of users it creates to a whitelist:

```
/whitelist
    uid1: true
    uid2: true
```

And then in your security rules only allow access on whitelisted users:

```
".read": "root.child('whitelist').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```